# Batch Rename files based on list of new names, but existing folder structure must be maintained

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, macos

I have a group of folders, each folder representing a different product that my record label has released.

Within each folder are the .wav audio files of the tracks that make up that release.

The current file naming structure of these .wav files means that they are not in any kind of order that relates to the actual running order of the product. I need to rename the files such that when arranged in ascending alphabetical order they represents the product's final running order.

Using various spreadsheets and data dumps i've been able to arrange the catalogue into a spreadsheet so that I can see all of the current filenames in one column, and their new desired file name next to it.

We're currently looking at 215 folders, containing around 900 .wav files

Is there a way that I can run some kind of Apple Script or terminal command to go through each folder in turn, lookup a filename in that folder, find a match in a .csv (for example) and rename the file appropriately?

Ideally it would be able to go through each of the 215 folders in turn — rather than me having to change the folder location each time and run the command manually 215 times

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it just filenames or the fully qualified path filenames you have in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Can be both — I'm just using the old trick of dragging the files into Text Edit (making sure it's in Plain Text mode) and it returns back the full path of each file :)

Comment: I'm not asking what it can be but what it is you have in the spreadsheet! Anyway, for such a small number of files I'd use the fully qualified path filenames to build out a bash script that will rename the 900 file in a few seconds using the `mv` command.